# R, merge multiple rows of text data frame into one cell

Tags: r, merge, text-mining

I have a text data frame that looks like below.

```
> nrow(gettext.df)
[1] 3

> gettext.df
 gettext
 1 hello,
 2 Good to hear back from you.
 3 I've currently written an application and I'm happy about it
```

I wanted to merge this text data into one cell (to do sentiment analysis) as below

```
> gettext.df
  gettext
  1 hello, Good to hear back from you. I've currently written an application and I'm happy about it
```

so I collapsed the cell using below code

```
paste(gettext.df, collapse =" ")
```

but it seems like it makes those text data into one chunk (as one word) so I cannot scan the sentence word by word.

Is there any way that I can merge those sentence as a collection of sentences, without transforming  as one big word chunk?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to transform the data frame column into a character vector before using `paste`.

```
paste(unlist(gettext.df), collapse =" ")
```

This returns:

```
[1] "hello, Good to hear back from you. I've currently written an application and I'm happy about it"
```

Comment: Or just work with the column vector: `paste(gettext$gettext, collapse =" ")`